# Faithfully clone a github repository

Tags: git, git-clone

I am trying to clone the Caffe SSD implementation: https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd

So I run:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe.git
$ ls caffe
```

and get the expected output, a list of the top level files, as seen on the github web interface.

but if I explore deeper, e.g.:

```
$ ls caffe/docker/
cpu   gpu   README.md
```

I get different files/folders to those appearing on the web interface (https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd/docker).

How can I fix this?

Comment: That *is* what I see in the web interface: https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/master/docker. Are you sure you're comparing the correct branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the branch `ssd` instead of `master`:

```
git clone -b ssd https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe.git
```

Comment: It's absolutely the same. [`-b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---branchltnamegt) is just a short alias for `--branch`.

Comment: I know it. Just to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that when you do a git clone by default you are in the master branch.
You want to switch to ssd branch. To do it:

```
git checkout ssd
```

And then you will see files of this branch. You can check wich branch are you using wit the following command:

```
git branch
```

Comment: with `git checkout -b` you will create a new branch. Maybe without the `-b` option?

Comment: yes, you are right. I have modified my answer. With -b you create a new branch.